# Orientdb: this java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM

Tags: jvm, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am getting "This java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM. Please install the desired version." error while running "server.bat"(orientdb-2.2.28) in windows 8.1(32-bit) . It was working fine till yesterday. Then,I removed "root" user and "isAfterFirstTime" tag from "orientdb-server-config.xml". From that time, it is giving error while running "server.bat" . Even after adding those lines back, it is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `-d64` switch at the end of the `server.sh` startup script and it worked. See issue [#7553](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/7553) for details or search for "-d64" in the [2.2 release notes](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/OrientDB-2.2-Release-Notes).